# (How) Can I emulate touch events on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, touch, multi-touch, wm-touch

A utility which I wrote in C++ for testing purposes currently uses the [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) function to emulate user input, i.e. mouse and keyboard events. I'd now like to extend my program such that it's able to emulate touch events, such that I can verify that the tested program handles e.g. [`WM_TOUCH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317341(v=vs.85).aspx) messages correctly (though that message [is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790602/wm-touch-vs-wm-pointer), I'd still like to verify that it's handled correctly). I don't need to be able to send touch events to a specific `HWND`, just sending them to some X/Y coordinates on the desktop is sufficient for my purposes.

I considered using [`HARDWAREINPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646269(v=vs.85).aspx) structures with `SendInput` as well as sending the `WM_TOUCH` (or `WM_GESTURE`?) message directly, but in either case it's not clear to me how to pass information about where or how that touch event was performed.

The `WM_TOUCH` documentation explains that the `lParam` argument:

> Contains a touch input handle that can be used in a call to GetTouchInputInfo to retrieve detailed information about the touch points associated with this message.

...but it's not clear if and how I can allocate such a 'touch input handle' myself. Is it always just a plain pointer in the address space of the current process? If so, what value should I use for the `hSource` field of the [`TOUCHINPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317334(v=vs.85).aspx) structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Touch injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802898(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: That looks perfect - I'm disappointed that I failed to find that myself. Thanks a lot for digging this up!